# SQL conditional extraction

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query which allow me to extract the current value of a column if this column has not be modified since the add of the object.

Or the last before the current value if the column was modified.

Note that the current value is saved in a table A and the history of modification in table B

Table A

```
ID
STATUS
other columns ....
```

Table B

```
ID
items_ID (which is the ID of element in table A)
modif_ID (indicate which column was modified)
old_value 
new_value
other columns..
```

Thanks in advance,

Imene.

For exemple, For table A

```
id  STATUS  Title   Description User

1   Closed  Help    Need help for configuring Apache    IBH

2   Solved  DSL DSL is down IBH

3   Assign  Hardware    Need new network cards  IBH
```

For table B

```
id  Items_id    Modif_id    Date_mod    Old_value   New value
1   1   1   12-02-2014  Assign  solved

2   1   1   15-02-2014  solved  closed

3   3   1   20-02-2014  New Assign

3   3   4   21-02-2014  hard    Hardware
```

All modif where the modif_id!=1 are ignored.

For each element id (Table A), we extract the current status if the status dosen’t change or the last before the current value if the status is changed one or more time.                                The expected result is:

```
id  STATUS

1   solved

2   solved

3   New
```

Comment: Please provide the data definitions and the query you've attempted.

Comment: A example build in SQLfiddle  can give insights to provide a better answer. You can use it http://sqlfiddle.com/